# Foundry call smart contract from with EOA address

Tags: testing, solidity

I am wtiting test case using [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs). I want to call a custom smart contract function that changes the state of the smart contract called from a EOA so the `msg.sender` would be the EOA address. Here is my testing code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import {console} from "forge-std/console.sol";
import {stdStorage, StdStorage, Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

import {Utils} from "./utils/Utils.sol";
import {MyERC20} from "../MyERC20.sol";

contract BaseSetup is MyERC20, DSTest {
    Utils internal utils;
    address payable[] internal users;

    address internal alice;
    address internal bob;

    function setUp() public virtual {
        utils = new Utils();
        users = utils.createUsers(5);

        alice = users[0];
        vm.label(alice, "Alice");
        bob = users[1];
        vm.label(bob, "Bob");
    }

    function test() {
       this.customFunction(); // want to call this function as Alice as the caller 
    }

}
```

So, in the code above, `customFunction` is defined on the `MyERC20` contract, and it changes the smart contract state. I want to call the function with different EOA accounts like `alice` and `bob`. Is it possible, and if so, what it the syntax for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `prank` [cheatcode](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/.) in foundry for this.

It's pretty straight forward.

```
interface CheatCodes {
           function prank(address) external;    
 }
contract Test is DSTest {
   CheatCodes cheatCodes;
   function setUp() public {
       cheatCodes = CheatCodes(HEVM_ADDRESS);
   }
   
   function test() public {
       // address(1337) is now the caller of customFunction
       cheatCodes.prank(address(1337));
       address(contract).customFunction();
   }
}
```

This pranked caller will only persist for a single call. Then you will have to instantiate the caller again with the `prank` cheatCode on future calls to the contract. Alternatively there is also a cheatCode called `startPrank` which will allow the custom caller to persist until `stopPrank` is called. Hope this helps!